# How to anchor a <div> to the lower left of a table cell without destroying responsiveness?

Tags: jquery, html, css, html-table, responsive-design

**The short of it is** that, in a table, on a responsive web page, I added a `<div>` within the `<td>`s and anchored it to the bottom left of the cell by putting `position: relative` on the `<td>` and

```
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
```

on the `<div>`.

That seems to have broken the page's responsiveness. Now, there is horizontal overflow scrolling on the whole page at a breakpoint of about `1260px`. Above that width, the page is fine; below that point, the horizontal overflow scrolling appears.

I need a CSS/jQuery solution to anchor the `<div>` to the table cell's lower left cornor without destroying the page's responsiveness. What I'm looking for is something like `float: left;` and `float: bottom;` together.

I tried making the `<td>` `display: flex;`, but that forced all the cells into a long column at the left.

**My question is two fold:**

**1)** Why was the page's responsiveness disrupted? (I'm learning. I'd like to understand.)

**2)** How can I achieve the goal of locking the `<div>` to the lower left and still keep the page responsive?

Currently, a typical `<td>` looks like this:

```
        <td id="x0900A">                    <!-- 0900 room A -->
            <p class="classTitle">
            </p>
            <div class="classDescrip">
            </div>
            <p class="instructor">
            </p>
            <p class="gender">
            </p>
            <div class="instructorBio">
            </div>
            <div class="instructorImg">
            </div>
            <div id="x0900A-roomCount" class="roomCount">
            <p id="x0900A-attending" class="attending">attending</p>
            <p id="x0900A-capacity" class="capacity">capacity</p>
            </div>
        </td>
```

It has this CSS:

```
.schedule td {
  position: relative;
}
div[id$=roomCount] {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 80px;
  margin: 10px 10px 0 5px;
  text-align: left;
  opacity: 0.60;
}
```

That worked to position the roomCount `<div>` where I want it, *but*, now, there is horizontal overflow scrolling on the whole page (`<body>`).

**Edit/Update:**

I reworked the question, editing out irrlevant information, I'm hoping this shorter, reworked version will get some attention.

Answer (score 0):

To be honest I am not 100% sure about what you are asking, however if you don't want the code to overflow add `overflow:hidden` to the td's element, this way nothing is able to run off screen, also in your code, the html as `id = "ect"` everywhere but there is not one `#etc` in your code.  Good luck

Edit : sorry for not recognizing the ID, I've just never seen it like that before

Comment: Thanks for your input. `div[id$=roomCount] {...}` is in the CSS. The ID's are for JavaScript that fills in content on page load. `overflow: hidden;` on the `<td>` does not cure the horizontal overflow scrolling on the page/body. I thought I was using the correct terminology to describe what happens. When one swipes left on the page, the whole page scrolls left leaving a black band at the right between the page edge and the viewport edge.  You can see the effect [here](https://www.familyhistoryconferencenwa.org/test-class-schedule-2019).

Comment: @alxfyv okay so I see what you mean now, I wasn't able to replicate the issue because my monitor width is bigger than the page width so I couldn't scroll. I only really have one idea, try setting
`body{overflow-x:hidden; width:100vw;}`
So this way nothing can go past the edges of your screen horizontally, however this disables you being able to scroll the whole page sideways, td's scroll shouldnt be affected though. I have no idea what caused this, and the space doesn't even show up in inspect element. If that doesn't work try adding `margin:0;` to body.

Comment: Thanks for your time and consideration. That [earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57061842/is-there-a-jquery-way-to-make-a-div-appear-at-the-lower-left-of-a-table-cell-t/57065393#57065393) that I alluded to got an answer that solved the problem. But I truly appreciate your help and effort.