# Is there a jQuery way to make a <div> appear at the lower left of a table cell that won't destroy responsiveness?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, html-table

I need to get a `<div>` to be at the bottom left corner of a table cell. Something like `float: left;` and `float: bottom;` together.

A typical cell is:

```
        <td id="x0900A">                    <!-- 0900 room A -->
            <p class="classTitle">
            </p>
            <div class="classDescrip">
            </div>
            <p class="instructor">
            </p>
            <p class="gender">
            </p>
            <div class="instructorBio">
            </div>
            <div class="instructorImg">
            </div>
            <div id="x0900A-roomCount" class="roomCount">
            <p id="x0900A-attending" class="attending">attending</p>
            <p id="x0900A-capacity" class="capacity">capacity</p>
            </div>
        </td>
```

The CSS is:

```
td {
  position: relative;
}
div[id$=roomCount] {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 80px;
  margin: 10px 10px 0 5px;
  text-align: left;
  opacity: 0.60;
}
.classTitle {
  float: left;
  margin: 5px 10px 10px 5px;
  padding: 0 5px 0 5px;
  line-height: 1.25em;
  font-size: 1.05em;
  text-align: left;
  color: #00b8b8;
}
.instructor {
  width: 50%;
  float: right;
  margin: 3px 0 10px 0;
  padding: 0 3px 5px 3px;
  line-height: 1.25em;
  font-size: 0.95em;
  text-align: right;
  color: #00b8b8;
}
.classDescrip,
.instructorBio,
.instructorImg,
.gender {
  display: none;
}
```

This locks `.roomCount` to the `<td>`'s bottom left but destroys responsiveness. I get horizontal overflow scrolling of the whole `<body>`. You can see the result [here](https://www.familyhistoryconferencenwa.org/test-class-schedule-2019).

I tried putting a wrapper `<div>` inside the `<td>` and making it

```
position: relative;
height: 100%;
```

but it's only so tall as the wrapped content requires which, for many cells, is only partway down.

So, I need a CSS/jQuery way to anchor `.roomCount` that doesn't break responsiveness.

**Note:**

This is a resubmission of an [earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57048151/how-to-anchor-a-div-to-the-lower-left-of-a-table-cell-without-destroying-respo) that was too wordy and had much irrelevant content. I'm resubmitting it here in the hope that it will garner notice.

**Edit/Update:**

In response to @UdoE's comment: I have included the code and edited the "wordiness." At least, I hope I have and made it a better question.

In response to @ChrisG's labeling this a possible duplicate: I already noted that this is a resubmission of that question and the reason why I did it. There are no answers or comments to that question as of this writing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to anchor a <div> to the lower left of a table cell without destroying responsiveness?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57048151/how-to-anchor-a-div-to-the-lower-left-of-a-table-cell-without-destroying-respo)

Comment: If you create a [mre], people are much more likely to try and solve this.

Comment: could wrap `<td>` contents in full height `<div>` that has relative position

Comment: A sample html code will suffice. This is also a little too wordy.

Comment: @charlietfl I tried that. I gave the wrapping `<div>` `height: 100%;`. It was only so high as its inner content required. The `<div>` anchored itself to the wrapper's bottom left, but, for many cells, that's not the full height of the cell.

Comment: @ChrisG Thanks for the comment. I thought to try but couldn't make a minimal case that reproduced the horizontal overflow scrolling. Also, I didn't see a link that would let me make a snippet. I still don't see one. I could be blind to it.

Comment: @UdoE. I put sample HTML and CSS in the question. Thank you. I hope I edited the wordiness to meet requirements. Boy, you guys are hard to write for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set `overflow: hidden;` on the div that wraps around the element:

`<div class="sqs-block code-block sqs-block-code" data-block-type="23" id="block-4f3956fa4071adb2096e">`

...the horizontal scroll on the body will go away. There is already a rule affecting this element in *site.css* on line 13:

```
.sqs-block:not(.sqs-block-html):not(.sqs-block-markdown) {
    clear: both;
    overflow: hidden; /* add this */
}
```

For keeping the `.roomCount` element positioned in the lower left of the cell, maybe this approach can help:

```
.schedule td {
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
}

div[id$="roomCount"] {
    margin: 0;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    max-height: 30px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

What this does is place 30px of padding at the bottom of the td. Then uses absolute positioning to move the `.roomCount` element into the lower left corner.

This way, even though absolute positioned elements are out of flow, the padding gives you an area to work with that is going to be accounted for when the table is resizing. I added a `max-height` and `overflow: hidden` on that element just in case. It will probably take some tweaking to get right for you.

[Here is a jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5m3wvp2e/)

Comment: *Gosh and golly!* That worked just the way you wrote it. About 60% of my traffic is from smartphones and tablets. I was worried. I don't see a way for me to reach site.css. Perhaps in developer mode, which I am not. But I just put a duplicate rule in custom CSS. Thanks for the explanation. I'm trying to learn.  Thanks again for your effort and time.

Comment: That makes sense, site.css is probably automatically included by Square space and putting it in custom CSS was the right move. :) I'm glad to have helped. Stack Overflow can be a tough place sometimes, the trick is to provide a working example of code people can use to troubleshoot. If I wasn't able to reach your site and see the issue first hand I wouldn't have been able to help based solely on the code you provided.

Comment: Jeramiah: Thanks for going the extra mile. I'll keep your advice well in mind if (when?) I come back with another problem. I'm concerned to write a good question because I don't want to embarrass myself or to waste StackOverflow members' time. I'm truly appreciative and I don't take getting an answer for granted.